# Something is wrong with sessions, never seen this one before

Tags: php, session

Yesterday, the I'm doing some work for had their website on one server. Everything worked fine. This morning I woke up, and my password didn't work. Got the new password from IT, and started hacking away at code.

Then I start getting these oddball errors. 
For example, I can login to an account, which stores an array of data in a session in php.

Here's where it get interesting.

If I had a session that was `$_SESSION['attributes']['ID']`, I could print it out, and get the value from it. But, when I try to evaluate against it, I'm always getting false as the return value, even when I assign it to a variable, like `$x = $_SESSION['attributes']['ID']`;

It's doing this across the entire system. Stuff that passed through Q/A weeks ago, and new stuff alike.

What the hell?

I've got root access, so I can fix it if it's a php.ini issue.
I just don't know where to look.

Have you ever seen this before?

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_SESSION['attributes']['ID'])`?

Comment: @andrewsi: Better yet: `var_dump($_SESSION)`.

Comment: if the code hasn't changed, then start investigating the underlying system. server updated? php updated? apache munged up?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yeah, that definitely couldn't hurt.

Comment: Prints out the values of the session, exactly like I would expect it to.

Comment: So, what happens when you do `$x = $_SESSION['attributes']['ID']`?  What does `var_dump($x)` show?  What do you mean by "always getting false as the return value"?  Are you sure you are comparing values right (eg: `==` vs `===`)?

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['attributes']['ID']) = string(5) "36275"

Comment: That's a string.  Are you comparing it with an int?  `$_SESSION['attributes']['ID'] === 36275` will be `false`.

Comment: Type isn't the problem here. I'm just checking to see that it's there. I can strlen against it, but if I run up against logic, it's returning false. I can't get an if statement to return true against it. 

And this is only the latest. 
It's doing this across the whole system.

Comment: what logic are you running it up against ? can you post some code for that ?

Comment: $_SESSION['attributes']['ID'] === 36275 will be false, but isset should return true.

Comment: Simplest thing in the world. Here's an example. 
`if(isset($_SESSION['attributes']['ID']) ){
   print $content;
  }`

Comment: So, `$content` doesn't get printed?

Comment: Right. Even if it has a value. Not only is content not getting printed, but if I put an else on that if statement, that block executes.

Comment: Could it be an ini setting related to sessions that's causing this?

Comment: So you're saying that `var_dump($_SESSION['attributes']['ID'])` returns something and `var_dump(isset($_SESSION['attributes']['ID']))` returns false? Even when you put both lines together in the same file?

Comment: No, it's only returning false when I apply the isset to an if statement.

Comment: Hang on, I wonder what E_ALL is going to tell me. BRB.

Comment: I'm curious what errors/warnings you get too :)

Comment: Nothing...
No errors, no warnings. huh.

Comment: Maybe they stuck me with an old version of php, like 5.1 or something. Checking.

Comment: Nope, version hasn't changed. Still on 5.3.3.

Comment: Can you replicate this on another machine? If so, can you rewind your code to a week ago to see if a recent change has affected something?

Comment: I put in an email to the helpdesk at the client. They purged the apache/php install, and re-installed both using yum. Looks like that solved the problem.

Comment: @halfer That's the thing. I've never seen this one before. No idea how it happened. If I knew what caused it, I would try to replicate it on a virtual box. I think I'm going to do some more digging and see if anyone else has seen a breakdown in basic logic in php before with 5.3. That was really odd.

Comment: Right, that was what I was aiming at - is it replicable on a new build? That wasn't clear from the question or the discussion. Anyway, pleased you've fixed it!

Comment: @halfer Would you believe that I hadn't looked into it before yesterday? The system is in a Vmware instance. Best guess is that it's a copy of a copy. Not sure where the original image is, or if one exists.

Comment: Ah, right. If you don't have your code in a version control repo, then that's the first thing to fix!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the same issue I had some weeks ago: I was able to stote data into a session and I was able to read those values in the same execution of the script. But an each reload of the script, the data was missing.

**The simple, yet hard to find error**:

The `session.save_path` has become unwritable for the apache user by some odd server process one of the admins was running each night (setting the owner of the folder to root).

I simply changed the path to the `upload_tmp_dir` (just in case the same admin is doing the same stupid misstake again) and the session text files could be successfully stored on the hdd again.

P.S. I couldn't find it the first place as the cookie was send successfully and the initialization also worked just fine. But as PHP was unable to write the session data to the disk, all "saved" data was lost after the script died.

Comment: That would make sense. They have an instance of Wordpress on the same machine, and they were doing some permissions changes to it for security reasons (I think).